# knife ssh node name wild card matching

Tags: chef, knife

I have a chef environment "dev",  We are switching our continuous integration build environment from jenkins to bamboo.  So we have a bunch of nodes names "jenkins_slave_??" and "bamboo_slave_??

I want to execute yum update -y on all of the jenkins_slave systems in the dev environment.  To test that knife only hits my desired servers, the following will execute the commands on all the hosts in the dev env.

```
knife ssh '*:dev' 'hostname; cat /etc/redhat-release '  -a cloud.public_ipv4 -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/dev.pem
```

The following will execute my command(s) on a specific host.

```
knife ssh '*:jenkins_slave_01' 'hostname; cat /etc/redhat-release '  -a cloud.public_ipv4 -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/dev.pem
```

I can't get

```
knife ssh '*:jenkins_slave_*' 'hostname; cat /etc/redhat-release '  -a cloud.public_ipv4 -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/dev.pem
```

or

```
knife ssh 'jenkins_slave_*:*' 'hostname; cat /etc/redhat-release '  -a cloud.public_ipv4 -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/dev.pem
```

to work.  How do I get knife to issue ssh commands to all hosts of a similar node name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hand face plant  sorry see my mistake dash not underscore

```
ssh '*:jenkins-slave*' 'hostname; cat /etc/redhat-release '  -a cloud.public_ipv4 -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/dev.pem
```